# reference model variable to global variable value in .net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, entity, global, razor-declarative-helpers

with curiosity...
i am seeking for a temporary solution that will lead to an expansions of a system side controller.

i a mvc3.net razor based project with 100+ of class file
all of the class file (model) has a system field

specific

```
public string u_by { get; set; }
public System.DateTime u_date { get; set; }
public System.DateTime c_date { get; set; }
public string c_by { get; set; }
public int version { get; set;
public int groupid { get; set; }
public int status { get; set; }
```

at the moment the useraccess control has not been build yet which in the end the useraccess controller will and suppose to fill in this variable.

i need to fixed the value for all the variable above during a form insert, update, delete

is there any where i can 
create a class and put a default value to it ?
i have created a

```
namespace webapp.Models
{
    public class sysfield
    {

        public string _updatedBy; 
        public string _createdBy;
        public DateTime _updatedDate;
        public DateTime _createdDate;
        public int _version;
        public int _groupid;
        public int _status;

        //Constructor
        public sysfield()
        {
            _updatedBy = HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName.ToString();
            _createdBy = HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName.ToString();
            _updatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            _createdDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            _version = updateVersion;
            _groupid = 100;
            _status = 1;
        }
        //Property 
        public int updateVersion
        {
            get 
            { 
                return _version; 
            }
            set 
            { 
                _version = _version + 1; 
            }
        }

        //Set Values
        public string createdBy(string initialCreator)
        {
            if (updateVersion == 1)
            {
                return _createdBy = initialCreator;
            }
            else
            {
                return _createdBy = HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName.ToString();
            }
        }

        public DateTime createdDate(DateTime initialDate)
        {
            if (updateVersion == 1)
            {
                return _createdDate = initialDate;
            }
            else
            {
                return _createdDate = System.DateTime.Now;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

now the question is how do i default it in code below, where when i insert the model

of

```
namespace webapp.Models
{
    public partial class usr_myapp
    {
        public int VEHID { get; set; }
        public string CARNAME { get; set; }
        public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
        public string TYPE { get; set; }
        public string u_by { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime u_date { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime c_date { get; set; }
        public string c_by { get; set; }
        public int version { get; set; }
        public int groupid { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
    }

}
```

with the Controller: 
Where user will fill in everything else except for the system field c_by,u_by, and etc...

```
    // POST: /myapp/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(usr_myapp usr_myapp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.usr_myapp.Add(usr_myapp);
            db.SaveChanges();  
        }

        return View(usr_myapp);
    }
```

---

how do i default the

```
`
 public ActionResult Create(usr_myapp usr_myapp)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.usr_myapp.Add(usr_myapp);
        db.SaveChanges();  
    }

    return View(usr_myapp);
}
```

`

where usr_myapp consist of

```
    public int VEHID { get; set; }
    public string CARNAME { get; set; }
    public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
    public string u_by { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime u_date { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime c_date { get; set; }
    public string c_by { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
    public int groupid { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
```

the partial class, i got it from the edmx generation should i be changing all of it?

a lost man in the amazing world

Comment: Are you sure the sysfield class compiles? That's a **horrbile** code it MUST be a better way to achieve what you want to achieve

Comment: yeah, guide me. i have made changes to the sysfield class.

Answer (score 0):

You set the defaults in the constructor. Do you have a specific need for it to be a partial class?